# DAX: Comparing Integer values to Text Values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a measure in PowerBI via DAX which provides a total number based on two filters. I drafted the following measure below and am getting an error stating " DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Integer with values of type Text. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values."

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( CASE_ACTIVE[EMPLOYEE_ID] ),
    FILTER (
        CASE_ACTIVE,
        TABLE[CASE_TYPE_ID] = "1"
            && CASE_ACTIVE[Category_Type] = "1"
    )
)
```

**Employee_ID:** Unique identifier for each employee

**Case_Type_ID:** Values identifying cases as "1" or "2"

**Category_Type:** Based on T/F; "1" True & "0" is False

I am running into issues when trying to convert the values so I get a total number of employees based on each of the filters. This is needed to create a cumulative value that can be compared against another value in an Area Chart.

Any help with solving is greatly appreciated.

Chameleon_Coder

Comment: Are you certain the values in `[Category_Type]` and `[Case_Type_ID]` columns are the text strings representing the numbers, and not the numbers themselves?  The error message is telling you there is a mismatch there.  And what is the formula you are using to translate `T/F` to `"1"/"0"`?

Comment: Have you tried using the DAX CONVERT function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/convert-function-dax

Comment: I'm wondering what your data model looks like.

Comment: My data model consists of two direct connections joined together from my database. Its a 1 to many relationship for the join. As for the T/F formula for Category_Type this is the formula I am using Category_Type = IF(CASE_ACTIVE[END_DATE]<=TODAY(),"1","0") and this is categorized as a whole number. Employee_ID is categorized as text and Case_Type_ID is also categorized as a whole number.

Comment: I am fairly new to the world of DAX and was ultimately trying to create an IF statement and the only solution I could come across was utilizing the CALCULATE function.

Comment: Found a workaround using a calculated column. It appears to be working as expected. Using the calculated column, I was able to use an IF statement to structure the column to form another T/F field.

Comment: Hello, You wrote this comment:"Category_Type = IF(CASE_ACTIVE[END_DATE]<=TODAY(),"1","0") and this is categorized as a whole number." How do you categorize it as whole number when your if statement returns text(string)? You used convert or INT() function somewhere? If it is so, then you are comparing string to integer which gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround using a calculated column. It appears to be working as expected. Using the calculated column, I was able to use an IF statement to structure the column to form another T/F field.